# Ошибка при запуске Telegram бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пытаюсь запустить простой телеграм-бот написанный на питоне,но выскакивает исключение:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(10061, 'Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение', None, 10061, None))
```

вот код:

```
import telebot
import os
token = '739370898:AAGPRwyTuI-_Gg2aGJa9i7vfXV_3z9cMt2U'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
@bot.message_handler(func=True, content_types=["text"])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text[::-1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.polling()
```

Comment: Сервер, к которому пытается подключиться бот, заблокирован РосКомНадзором.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, как тогда запустить телеграм бота?

Comment: Не на территории РФ или через VPN.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, а как через vpn запустить?

Comment: Настроить VPN-подключение на хосте где запускаете бота, активировать его, а потом запустить бота.

Comment: а можно через прокси сервера запустить?

Comment: [Можно](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#proxy), но нет гарантии, что поможет. Зависит от вашего провайдера.